# Change the "under review" date after revision

Tags: peer-review

I submitted a paper to a journal in Springer system. After a revision, I resubmitted the revised paper to the system, and the system change the status to "Under review" on Nov 24. After that, the status didn't change but the date was changed to Dec 06.

I wonder that what can cause this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/62750/change-in-under-review-date?rq=1).